# How can I Change Form Colour When I switch from Dark to Light mode in React

Tags: reactjs, forms, toggle, mode

Hello guys I got the following code in my app.js:

```
function App() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState('light');
  const toggleTheme = () => {
    if (theme === 'light') {
      setTheme('dark');
    } else {
      setTheme('light');
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    document.body.className = theme;
  }, [theme]);
  return (
    <div className={`App ${theme}`}>
       <button onClick={toggleTheme}>Toggle Theme</button>
```

And the Following Css in my Form:

```
.form-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: rgb(54, 118, 139);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

So How can I change the  background-color of my Form When Dark is toggled and When Light is toggled? Im using react coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you use css variables for this. Assuming that you're setting the class names `light` and `dark` on the body itself. they should be applied automatically according to your theme on the form.

```
.light {
  --form-bg: #4d4d4d;
}
.dark {
  --form-bg: #e1e1e1;
}

.form-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 750px;
  background-color: var(--form-bg);
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `className` value of your form-container based on the theme.

jsx:

```
...
   <form className={theme === "light" ? "form-container light" : "form-container dark"}>
...
```

css:

```
.form-container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 750px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.form-container.light {
  background-color: rgb(54, 118, 139);
}

.form-container.dark {
  background-color: black;
}
```